# Compilation error in compiling Protobufs in Java using SBT build tool

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf-c

I am using the Play framework (which uses SBT build tool) with Java where I need to consume a Protobuf. So I have `xxx.proto` file. I got binary protoc compiler and added to class path. so I see -

> protoc --version
> libprotoc 3.1.0

I have compiled the xxx.proto file using -
`protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/xxx.proto` so it has generated xxx.java file.

Now when I am compiling this xxx.java file ( the project using sbt build tool)

```
[error] /my_project/app/helpers/xxx.java:7: package com.google.protobuf        does not exist
[error] com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite
[error] /my_project/app/helpers/xxx.java:11: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
[error] com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry
[error] /my_project/app/helpers/xxx.java:6182: package com.google.protobuf.Descriptors does not exist
[error] com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor
[error] /my_project/app/helpers/xxx.java:6185: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 does not exist
[error] com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.FieldAccessorTable`
```

I see in my installed library - `com.google.protobuf` jar is there.

My `xxx.proto` looks following -

```
 // Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
 // source: xxx.proto

 public final class xxx {
 private xxx() {}
 public static void registerAllExtensions(
  com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite registry) {
 }

  public static void registerAllExtensions(
  com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) {
   registerAllExtensions(
    (com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite) registry);
 }
 ......
```

Is there anything I have missed while generating the `xxx.java` file?
How should I fix these compilation error?

Comment: I just want to add that I already have protobuf-java-2.0.5 jar in my library root.

Comment: For some reason the compiler does not see the the protobuf library, probably an issue with the sbt build rule. Are you sure sbt uses your library root? Did you try compiling the xxx.java manually with javac and protobuf-java-2.0.5.jar in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, javac xxx.java -cp $PATH_TO_Protobuf_jar/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar But still it gives errors -xxx.java:6188: error: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 does not exist
    com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.FieldAccessorTable
                                          ^
xxx.java:6193: error: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 does not exist
    com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.FieldAccessorTable

Comment: Is there a newer version available? The "V3" suffix seems to suggest you'd need protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar or later?

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure that you're using the exact same versions of `protoc` and `libprotobuf.jar`. From what you wrote, it sounds like you're using protoc version 3.1.0 but libprotobuf 2.5.0. You need to use libprotobuf 3.1.0 instead, otherwise you will get compile errors like the ones you quote.

Answer (score 1):

Re-stating Kenton's answer with some more instructions:

In Intellij, click on External Libraries and find the jar for protobuf.

[image]

Check the version of protoc:

[image]

If they don't match, (as shown above) then you will get the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issue with maven after changing some field type in my proto schema and then building without doing a clean first. However, doing a clean and build fixed it every time.